# What is the software used for integer programming

Tags: optimization

What is the software used for integer programming?

please let me know the methods. I have tried with simplex method. But I am trying to solve is MINLP. Any light on solving that? Suggest solvers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your MINLP model is convex (has convex relaxations), non-convex but local solutions are ok, or non-convex and global solutions are needed different solvers are suitable. But here is a small list of the ones I regularly use:

- [Bonmin](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin) (open source)
- [Dicopt](https://www.gams.com/help/topic/gams.doc/solvers/dicopt/index.html)
- [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron) (global)
- [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne) (global, open source)
- [Antigone](http://helios.princeton.edu/ANTIGONE/) (global)

Furthermore quadratic models can also be solved by solvers like Cplex and Gurobi. Finally, many MINLP models can be reformulated into something more manageable, sometimes even into straight MIP models.

You can try out a number of MINLP solvers at http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/ (section Mixed Integer Nonlinearly Constrained Optimization).